# Creating PDF from UIView in iphone app gives exception

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, uiview

I am creating pdf from iphone app using following code but when i call this method it gives exception.I have got this code from site.

here is the code

```
    -(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
    {


// Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

// Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


// draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

[aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

// remove PDF rendering context
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

// Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

// instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
[pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);


 }
```

I am calling this method here

```
    [self createPDFfromUIView:self.view];
```

i think problem is in parameter passing while calling method.
thanks

here is the exception Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainViewController createPDFfromUIView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x613a950'

Comment: What is that exception pls share it.

Comment: @Impossible here is the exception Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainViewController createPDFfromUIView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x613a950'

Comment: you have to pass pdf name with your function call like [self createPDFfromUIView:self.view saveToDocumentsWithFileName:@"Test"];

Comment: @Impossible again exception Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainViewController createPDFfromUIView::]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6156660'

Comment: @Impossible thanks it worked but it does not show whole content it just show part of the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation says it all

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
```

Expects 2 parameters ad you have specified only 1, so instead of

```
[self createPDFfromUIView:self.view];
```

Try

```
[self createPDFfromUIView:self.view saveToDocumentsWithFileName:@"Name of the file"]
```

Comment: yes it is working but when I NSLog the file it shows path and when find that path it does not show that path

Comment: it is creating pdf but it does not show the whole view it just shows half i have a view in which i have scrollver view and i am adding content in scroller view so it show all the view

Comment: @AliImran: I have never tried creating pdf files from `UIScrollView`. But it seems others have also faced same issue. Hope this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553895/uigraphicsgetcurrentcontext-and-uiscrollview

Comment: can you please edit in my code how may i use this i am not clear about the link you have given