# Create PDF from UIView in iOS 5.1 Landscape doesnt work

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiview

I'm trying to create a PDF from a UIView and works well, as "[How to Convert UIView to PDF within iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443166/how-to-convert-uiview-to-pdf-within-ios)" did. 
But my iPad is landscape and is a form, lengthy form, with height 3k. 
When I convert to PDF, it converts only the size of the height of the iPad, namely 748 and not 3k I need.

What is wrong? The iOS version?

EDITED: Heres the code like @wain ask

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
    [aView drawRect:aView.bounds];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

Comment: Show the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution from here "[UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext and UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553895/uigraphicsgetcurrentcontext-and-uiscrollview)" and adaptate to my code and now grab all form and print a nice PDF.
If someone need my code, please let me know and i post the code.